# MapStateToProps to component state in an sync context

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-saga, react-state

I know we can easily send the content of `mapStateToProps` in the component's state by doing so :

```
constructor(props){
  super(props);

  this.state = {
     filteredApps: this.props.apps
  }
}
```

In this usecase, `this.state.filteredApps` gets filled with what was mapped to props from Redux.

But what if `this.props.apps` is only filled properly after an async call? In an async context, `this.props.apps` will probably be an empty array for when it is initialized until the real data is fetched. Take this as an example :

```
class AppFilterer extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      filteredApps : this.props.apps
    }
  }

  componentWillMount() {
      this.props.getApps();
  }

  render(){ return <div> </div> }

}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
   let { apps } = state.Admin;
   return { apps };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getApps })(AppFilterer);
```

In this case, my Redux action (which is caught by an Saga) `this.props.getApps();` is the call that fills my `props` full of apps and is called from the `componentWillMount` function. It is initialized as an empty array and then gets filled with apps once the call is complete.

I wish to filter these apps once they are fetched from the API so want to put them inside my component's state so that I don't mess with the Redux state. What is the best practice for updating the component's state in this case? In other words, is there any way to take the result of a saga that has been mapped to props and set it into the component's state or am I looking for a weird pattern and should filter it some other way?

Comment: Dont mix state with props, if your prop is changing, use it direct in your component instead of storing it in local `state`

Comment: @Rikin what if I then need to filter it? The apps props will be readonly when I use it directly inside my component.

Comment: It seems you are fetching it from Redux anyway as `apps` is destructured from `state.Admin` so even there its going to stay the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all API calls go in `componentDidMount` not in `componentWillMount` which is also now deprecated. Please refer this guide:

> https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html

Secondly, when you are using redux state and mapping it to props, you should not set that in your component local state, that’s not a good practice. You’ll receive updated props when your promise will return and you can always rely on props in that scenario.

But if you still want to do that you can override `componentDidUpdate(prevProps)` which will be called when your props or state is updated. Here is where you can set your state if you still want to do that.

**Note for your filter thing**

You can do filtering in `componentDidUpdate` method like:
`this.setState({filteredApps. this.props.apps.filter(<your filter logic>)})`

Comment: Thanks for the infos I will update my code. No I don't want to use this pattern given it is bad practice but I still don't understand what the good practice would be then if I need to use it inside my component and then filter the list. Simply drop it inside the component as a props?

Comment: If you want to filter data in your local state then that you can do. You can do what you are doing right now. Just implement `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle method as I mentioned in the answer.

Comment: Please see Note added at the end of my answer.